# Error messages are not getting logged. I have created an Add-In button. I am using log4Net library for logging.

Tags: arcobjects, c#, add-in, log

When i run Add-In button project on my machine, logging is being done successfully but as soon as i take the Add-In button and install it into different machine , no logging of messages occurs. Is it because log4net library is not being added in different machine during add-in button installation?